# Generating updater.exe via Advanced Installer command line

Tags: advanced-installer

I am trying to sign all executables + dll files in my application, within an Azure Pipeline, using Azure signtool for that. (doing basically the described [here](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/using-azure-key-vault.html)) - on the result of running dotnet publish.

Exception is updater.exe, because it is generated by Advanced Installer API or some other proprietary way. Signing the updater.exe file that lies inside Advanced Installer installation folder /x86/updater.exe - does not help (it will work, but the updater.exe that is deployed when installing the MSI is not signed, meaning it is generated during processing of the .AIP file, which happens after running dotnet publish)

Is there a way the updater.exe AI generates (with the custom icon, etc) to be created using AdvancedInstaller.com command line API ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered in the forums here:

https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=50297#p127034

Comment: I do not think so. I have just added a reply.